# Converting NFA to regular expression

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

[image]

Here is the regular expression I made for it

This is my first answer, used the naive method aka don't know what am doin' method.
$$
\epsilon \cup a^* \cup (a^*b) \left((a| b^*a) | \left( (a|(b^*a))ba^*\right) \right) ^*
$$

this is my re-worked answer, with the state removal method.

$$
\left( a^* \cup (b)(a \cup bb^*a) \right) ^*
$$

steps taken :

1. Add a new start state and a new final state.
2. Add epsi transitions to the new states.
3. Remove Q2
4. Link between Q1 and Q3 is now $a \cup bb*a$
5. Remove Q1
6. Add a new link between Q0 and Q3 with $ (b)(a U bb*a)$ label
7. Remove Q0
   There are three paths. a*, the big regex and the start with epsi
   $\epsilon \cup a* \cup (b)(a \cup bb*a)$
8. Remove Q3
9. We get $\epsilon \cup \left( a^* \cup (b)(a \cup bb^*a) \right) ^*$ =$ \left( a^* \cup (b)(a \cup bb^*a) \right) ^*$

**My questions are:**

- Is my regular expression correct ?
- What happens if it loops ?

To be clear, let's say we have the string aababaaaaabab

I think that string is recognized by the NFA, but I'm not sure it is by my regular expression.

does the $^*$ at the end cover it correctly ?

ps: As suggested I moved this from math.se

Comment: You've already included a full answer to the question so there's nothing left for us to do except say "yes" or "no". And I don't understand what you mean by "what if it loops?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby Im glad my answer is working. I wasn't sure about it and asked for a verification, didn't know that wasn't allowed here, I often do that on math.se

Comment: @DavidRicherby By looping, I meant the fact that a string would be a valid one concatened with other valid ones. I'm not sure if the only thing I need is the ^* at the end.

Comment: The automaton accepts $bab$ but your regular expression doesn't.

Comment: @DavidRicherby yeah right. I tryed to fix it but I'm confused. Can you tell me which step is wrong.  Pretty sure its step 5 and 6.

Comment: same as @DavidRicherby, try with this strings, because fails it the regular expression: bab, abbbbbbab.

Comment: @Dave I don't know which step is wrong. There is a standard technique for converting automata to regular expressions. Apply the technique correctly and you will get the right answer. We're not here to debug for you.

Comment: @DavidRicherby What “standard technique” are you referring to? I ask because so far I came across two in Hopcroft's [*Introduction to Automata Theory*](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Automata-Theory-Languages-Computation/dp/0321455363), then one in Brzozowsik's paper [*Derivatives of Regular Expressions*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321249), and various informal or incomplete mentions of NFA to RE conversion in different academic slides.

Comment: @Jens OK, fine. "There are multiple standard techniques." The point is that one can look this up in any number of existing resources.

Comment: This is the correct answer: `^a*(b(b+)?a(ba*(b(b+)?a)?)*)?$`  See this link: https://regexr.com/41bs2

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem, I propose a regular expression in a ad-hoc meth, and the outcome was: (notation comes from [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression))

> `(a*(b(b+)?ab?)?)*`

I found it with the next methodology: moving from simple to more complex ( states to final states)

- To arrive to $q_3$, you need to put `a`
- This `a` comes from $q_1$ or $q_2$
- If it comes from $q_1$, use a `b` else it comes from $q_2$, so use one o more `b`'s: `b+`
- But, $q_2$ comes from `b` too, so union these two possibilities, `a` comes from `b((b+)?)`
- For that, we have `b(b+)?a` in regular expression to go from $q_1$ to $q_3$
- Now, If you want to move from $q_3$ to $q_0$, you need a extra `b`, so use `b?`. This is the part of regular expression: b(b+)?ab?
- To start you probably have empty string, or `a`'s or `b` to go from $q_0$ to $q_1$
- Above can achieve with `a*` and visit $q1$ or not visit is express like: `a*(b(b+)?ab?)?`
- Finally, you could have a nothing of that, or more than once this strings, so you should use `*`, and take as regular expression: `(a*(b(b+)?ab?)?)*`

### Test Cases

I tested with the next strings and all match with the regex:

1. `aaaaba`
2. `aababaaaaaa`
3. `abbbbbba`
4. `abbbbbbab`
5. `abbbbbbabaaaa`
6. `abbbbbbaba`
7. `bab`
8. `ba`
9. `babaaaa`
10. `aaaaa`
11. `bbba`

In the other hand, you may be interested in consider algorithms to converting DFA to Regular expression, so you can find a dynamic programing algorithm, and the full description of this approach is given in the book of [*Models of Computation*](http://cs.brown.edu/people/jes/book/pdfs/ModelsOfComputation.pdf), Chapter 4. And other method, [Brzozowski algebraic method.](http://www.liacs.nl/~marcello/FI2/DFA_to_RE.pdf) All above, because with the [powerset constructive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) you can obtain a DFA from NFA.

Comment: There is a standard technique for converting automata to regular expressions, which is proven to be correct. I'm not sure why one would use an ad-hoc technique and then try to justify it by a bunch of examples. Also, please explain your non-standard notation: I assume that $x+$ is $xx^*$ and $x?$ is $(x|\epsilon)$: if so, $(b+)?$ is just $b^*$.

Comment: 0k, You can notice that my notation comes from regular expression in programming languages and I think it's good to know http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression, in a standard presentation. And other hand, If you can prove that this ad-hoc it's wrong, please, show me. It would be for me a profit. This ad-hoc approach, is more a constructive and inductive way, so am I completely wrong?. Test cases is not a proof, It just for play with regex.

Comment: Your regex is not correct. This is the correct answer: `^a*(b(b+)?a(ba*(b(b+)?a)?)*)?$`  See this link: https://regexr.com/41bs2

Comment: Why is wrong? Can you please make the point out?